# Why function gives difference results with print and return

Tags: python, function

If i code:

```
a = [56, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 6, 2, 56, 2, 6, 2, 52, 5, 2]


def func1(a3):
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] + a[i+1] == 58:
            print(a[i])
func1(a)
```

I get in output:
56
2
56

But if i code return a[i] instead of print(a[i]) i get only first suitable number
How can i fix it?

Comment: 1st: your *func* takes an argument (*a3*) but it's ignored, and it  uses the *a* directly.  What should the output be?

Answer (score 1):

Your code exits out of the function when it encounters a return statement. So the following iterations dont happen. If you need a list of values that you were going to print, take a empty array and then append to it whenever you want to print and then return that list when the for loop is over

```
a = [56, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 6, 2, 56, 2, 6, 2, 52, 5, 2]


def func1(a3):
    ans = []
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] + a[i+1] == 58:
            ans.append(a[i])
    return ans
func1(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` function causes your function to "stop running", returning the value passed in parameter. If you want to return more than the first element, you might want to create a list in which you append the desired elements.

```
a = [56, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 6, 2, 56, 2, 6, 2, 52, 5, 2]
def func1(a3):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] + a[i+1] == 58:
            result += [a[i]]
func1(a)
```

Comment: Do you mean `result = 0`? rather than `[]`

Comment: I forgot the brackets. I edited my answer.